# Exclude folder from Spotlight indexing - via command line

Tags: macos, command-line, spotlight

Is there a command-line way to exclude folders from spotlight indexing?  To do it via UI, you can use **System Preferences >> Spotlight >> Privacy**.  But I'd like to be able to add various folders/directories to that Privacy list via command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure this isn't exactly what you meant by 'via command line', but you can add the extension '.noIndex' to a folder to have it ignored by Spotlight, or create an empty file in the folder named '.metadata_never_index'.

Comment: As of macOS Mojave the 2nd option (adding a '.metadata_never_index' file) doesn't work anymore. I.e. macOS ignores it.

Comment: `touch .metadata_never_index` is a completely valid way to accomplish the task "via command line" !!  